# changing the position of the the first letter

Tags: css

how to change the position of "h" which in "hello" and change its width using css and without modifying the div element,
I have tried the pseudo element `first-letter`, but it didn't work for me

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  width: 290px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

div::first-letter {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>hello, this my code.</div>
```

Comment: U can use span tag and style it separately or some semantic tag for strong or bold text too

Answer (score 1):

The first-letter is working fine. There is also another method to place the first in the span tag and styling it.

```css
div {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  width: 290px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

div span {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div><span>h</span>ello, this my code.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float for this task:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  width: 290px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

div::first-letter {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div>hello, this my code.</div>
```

Comment: but is there a way to change the width & the height as they don't change

Comment: @Ahmed you can play with padding and font-size but not width or height

Answer (score -1):

Hey unfortunately CSS cant select first letter by itself. You can use another div for example;

```
<h1><span>H</span>ello</h1>

h1 { font-size: 1.3rem;}
h1 span {font-size:1.5rem;}
```

of course you can address direct name or you can access to that span element in different ways. But dont forget span by itself doesn't change the document placing etc that's why we prefer using this element for actions like that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter#:~:text=The%20%3A%3Afirst%2Dletter%20CSS,as%20images%20or%20inline%20tables and the other answers say otherwise

Comment: Hey thank you for the link i didn't know that feature i'll edit my post ASAP :)